# Does pokemon moves have a correlation on evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you evolve a pokemon its moves are randomized and you get a new set of moves based on the new evolution.

Are the moves completely random or is there any correlation, any way to predict what moves there might be except checking for possible moves in websites like: http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-list

Comment: completely random

Comment: @dly please link a source if you have one

Comment: @Sync personal experience. If several pokemon with the same attack moves have different moves after their evolution there can't be a pattern.

Comment: @dly okay thanks for clarifying. Pokemon Go seems to have quite a few easter eggs (ex. Picking Eevee evolutions by nicknames), I'm wondering if there is some way of getting desired pokemon moves by renaming it to something.